# Comparing dataframe of different lengths with several duplicates and extracting rows

Tags: r, duplicates, comparison, row

I am working with R version 3.2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.
I have two dataframes, that we can call DF1 (716,757 observations with 6 variables) and DF2 (716,733 observations with 6 variables). I would like to compare every rows of DF1 to DF2 to know which row was added/removed. The problem is that in one dataframe several rows are duplicated, but ordered in time. My idea is to compare every line between DF1 and DF2 and record all the added/removed row. Is there any way for doing this? Please find below an example of what I would like to do.

DF1

```
 V1       V2         V3          V4    V6        V7
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.1   X19    001:00:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.1   X19    001:00:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.1   X19    001:00:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.2   X19    000:15:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.2   X19    000:15:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.2   X19    000:15:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.1   Y18    000:45:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.2   Y18    000:15:00
B20      02     2016-01-01       A.1   Z85    003:00:00
B20      02     2016-01-01       A.2   Z85    000:40:00
```

DF2

```
 V1       V2         V3          V4    V6        V7
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.1   X19    001:00:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.1   X19    001:00:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.1   X19    001:00:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.2   X19    000:15:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.1   Y18    000:45:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.2   Y18    000:15:00
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.1   Y18    000:15:00
B20      02     2016-01-01       A.1   Z85    003:00:00
B20      02     2016-01-01       A.2   Z85    000:40:00
```

Output of missings/addings

```
 V1       V2         V3          V4    V6        V7
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.2   X19    000:15:00 (missing in DF2)
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.2   X19    000:15:00 (missing in DF2)
C86      44     2016-01-01       A.1   Y18    000:15:00 (added in DF2)
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: ?dplyr::anti_join

Comment: And `semi_join` as well.

Comment: Thank you to both of you! That's exactly what I was looking for!!!